# Mouse position during a function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to get the pixel-coordinates of the mouse position during a call of a function (`exe_datepicker`). This function is being executed inside quite a big framework (inside the so called arcplan 8.7 HTML5-client). Thus certain restrictions apply:

- There's no chance to select any DOM-objects because the IDs/names are not retrievable
- My  exe_datepicker function is called through an arcplan-function.
- I cannot access other objects or functions of the arcplan - Framework

What  I try to do here:

1. Create a temporary object (`tobj`) and append it to the body
2. Move it to the mouse position
3. Use the datepicker on that `tobj`
4. Through an API the selected date will be returned to the arcplan blackbox
5. Destroy the `tobj`

My only problem is to move the `tobj` on to the mouse position. How could I achieve this as someone being a beginner in JS and with the restriction of letting it happen inside the `exe_datepicker` function (the one being called when clicking on that icon)?

Thank you!

Edit: Sorry, looks like the code hasn't been posted in my first try.

```js
function exe_datepicker(objekt,dateiname,sprache,miniDat,maxiDat) {
 $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "" ] );
 $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ sprache ] );
 $('<input type="text"  id="dummy_'+objekt+'" name="dummy_'+objekt+'" readonly="readonly">').appendTo("body");

 
 //I tried to play around here, but event.pagex is always undefined inside the alert.
 $(this).one("click", function(event) {

           alert("clicked " + event.pageX);
   
          });
 
 var tobj = $('#dummy_'+objekt+'');
 
 $(this).trigger( "click" );

 tobj.css({
  "position":"absolute",
  "top":0, //mouse position y
  "left":0, //mouse position x
  "z-index":"100000",
  "border":"0px",
  "width": $("#datepick"+objekt+"").css("width"),
  "height": $("#datepick"+objekt+"").css("height"),
  "font-family": "Lucida Sans Unicode"
 });

 tobj.datepicker({
   showButtonPanel: true,
   dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
   firstDay: 1,
   regional: sprache,
   changeMonth: true,
   showWeek: true, 
   minDate: miniDat,
   maxDate: maxiDat,
   onClose: function () 
        {
         tobj.remove();
        }
  });
 
 tobj.change(function() 
  {
   
   ARCPLAN.arcclient.acSendInputEvent(dateiname, objekt, tobj.val(), 1, 1);
   tobj.remove();
  }
 );
 
 tobj.mouseover(function() 
  {
   $('#dummy_'+objekt+'').focus();
  }
 ); 
 tobj.mouseout(function() 
  {
   $('#dummy_'+objekt+'').focus();
  }
 );
 $('#dummy_'+objekt+'').focus();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="arcComponentContainer" tabindex="-1" style="z-index: 70;left: 938px;top: 138px;width: 16px;height: 16px"><button style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.0);border-top-width:0px;border-bottom-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;border-right-width:0px;border-top-color:rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.75);border-bottom-color:rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.75);border-left-color:rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.75);border-right-color:rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.75);border-style:outset;font-family:'Arial';font-size:9pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;color:#000000;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;" class="arcButton" tabindex="0"><img width="16px" height="16px" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAIAAACQkWg2AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0&#10;d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyJpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9i&#10;ZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2Vo&#10;aUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6&#10;bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuMC1jMDYxIDY0&#10;LjE0MDk0OSwgMjAxMC8xMi8wNy0xMDo1NzowMSAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpS&#10;REYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJk&#10;Zi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIg&#10;eG1sbnM6eG1wTU09Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9tbS8i&#10;IHhtbG5zOnN0UmVmPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvc1R5&#10;cGUvUmVzb3VyY2VSZWYjIiB4bWxuczp4bXA9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5j&#10;b20veGFwLzEuMC8iIHhtcE1NOkRvY3VtZW50SUQ9InhtcC5kaWQ6QzNEOEQx&#10;RjI1NUZFMTFFNTgxODE4NTlGNjhGRTk1MDUiIHhtcE1NOkluc3RhbmNlSUQ9&#10;InhtcC5paWQ6QzNEOEQxRjE1NUZFMTFFNTgxODE4NTlGNjhGRTk1MDUiIHht&#10;cDpDcmVhdG9yVG9vbD0iQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENTNS4xIFdpbmRvd3Mi&#10;PiA8eG1wTU06RGVyaXZlZEZyb20gc3RSZWY6aW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmRp&#10;ZDpGQUFCRkZGNkZENTVFNTExQUFGNzg4RkI3MkM3NUQzOCIgc3RSZWY6ZG9j&#10;dW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRpZDpGQUFCRkZGNkZENTVFNTExQUFGNzg4RkI3MkM3&#10;NUQzOCIvPiA8L3JkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbj4gPC9yZGY6UkRGPiA8L3g6eG1w&#10;bWV0YT4gPD94cGFja2V0IGVuZD0iciI/PqxYR5gAAABqSURBVHjaYvz//z8D&#10;AwPjpHNA8n+eEQMGQJYCshkhGogEQA1MDCQCkjWwwF1JEEC8QbGTgMZATMJk&#10;UOAHzFDHyoC5ARgPE8/+BwOCDCBJspNAMU18sCJimmDgUBxKhAMHWQNWq3EB&#10;gAADAL5DXK0N5uLcAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC&#10;"></button></div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only track the mouse coordinates in an mouse event handler, so I'd suggest to create your own, and store the mouse coordinates in a global variable:

```
var mouse = { x:0, y: 0 };
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  mouse.x = e.clientX;
  mouse.y = e.clientY;
});
```

Then in your code you can reference `mouse.x` and `mouse.y`. The coordinates are relative to the document.

For setting the position of `tobj`:

```
tobj.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
tobj.style.top  = mouse.y + 'px';
```

Of course, you must make sure that `tobj` can be moved. To achieve this, you may need to apply some CSS to it:

```
style="position: absolute; display: block"
```

Comment: the moment the function runs he will have to cache the coordinates. the mouse may move afterwards

Comment: @eltonkamami: Which function? The `mousemove` event handler? It caches the coordinates; that's the whole point, no?

Comment: from OP `I am trying to get the pixel-coordinates of the mouse position during a call of a function (exe_datepicker)` although not sure if access is provided to that function and is not a library one

Comment: He will take the coordinates from the global `mouse` object in that function. I miss your point...

Comment: hi, whether the mouse will move a few pixel won't matter as long as the datepicker opens near the mouse, even though a button was clicked. However, trincot's approach looks as though it will work. I'll reply in a bit to that. Thank you guys!

The exe_datepicker is my own function that I have added to that huge JS-blackbox, as far as my customizign skill allowed it.

Comment: if for any reason the access to your mouse global object is done at a time after and in the meantime the mouse has moved, wrong coordinates will be fetched. given the single thread nature of js this will happen only if `exe_datepicker` is asynchronous. so in general you will be ok

Comment: No, exe_datepicker will be executed immidiately. thank you!

Comment: well, actually eltonkamami's point is true. If I drag the mouse very quickly away from that button the datepicker will show up at the current mouse position. But that's definately a flaw I can live with.

Comment: This might indeed happen if a relative long processing (like more than a few hundreds of a second) precedes the move of the datapicker. A possible work-around is that you postpone the move of the datepicker with `setTimeout(...., 0)`: this will make the already queued mousemove events to be consumed by the mousemove event handler (updating `mouse`) just before your deferred function would kick in, which should just do the move only (so not spending a lot of time on other things).

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that the framework isn't also giving you an Event Object?
in case you should be able do get quite easily mouse position
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_clientx.asp

Comment: Hi, to be honest I do not know what objects are available. Too many to analyse for my very limited skill.

Comment: have you tried setting a breakpoint in the click callback and watching parameter 'event'?, Instead of pageX probably clientX/Y properties should be used [refer to my link].
setting an eventlistener on mousemove uses a lot of cpu time, i would avoid it

Comment: There is indeed some stuff going on when adding a breakpoint. Unfortunately I am too much a beginner to make anything out of it.
I see that inside the Chrome console. There's a Local scope and a Global Scope. Inside the local one, there's a level b with an event that contains my desirent coordinated. No idea how to reference that, though. 
Inside the global hierarchy there is also an event-knot hosting the desired clientX value. Also i don't know how to reference that. If I only use event.clientX there's an undefined value returned.

Comment: Of course the global window.event is empty because during my function call there event.clientX does not exist anymore. The click probably just fires another function... I would probably have to create a new prototype or something of the v.handler (that stores the clientX/Y coordinates locally during the onclick) and update some variables each time there's a click? But that seems beyond my skill once again ;(

Comment: try to place a console.log(event) below your handler definition
 //I tried to play around here, but event.pagex is always undefined inside the alert.
 $(this).one("click", function(event) {
console.log(event)

i think there you should find the informations you need

Comment: I'll play around with that, thank you :-) However,
I may have just come up with quite an obvious way to save cpu-power: Instead of using document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e)  I would use document.addEventListener('click', function (e) and save the coordiantes.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to your help I was able to fulfill my desire to have a jQuery datepicker in our reporting application ;-)
The below Javascript is part of a custom javascript file that is being loaded with all the other stuff.

```js
//New part suggested here

var mouse = { x:0, y: 0 };
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) { //Taking into account User's remark about CPU time here. Plus no more lagging between opening the function and displaying the datepicker
  mouse.x = e.clientX;
  mouse.y = e.clientY;
});

//Ausführen des Datepickers aus Arcplan heraus via STARTENJS
function exe_datepicker(objekt,dateiname,sprache,miniDat,maxiDat) {
 $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "" ] );
 $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ sprache ] );
 $('<input type="text"  id="dummy_'+objekt+'" name="dummy_'+objekt+'" readonly="readonly">').appendTo("body");

 //alert(mouse.x + ' ' + mouse.y);
 
 var tobj = $('#dummy_'+objekt+'');
 
  tobj.css({
  "position":"absolute",
  "top":mouse.y, //mouse position y
  "left":mouse.x, //mouse position x
  "z-index":"100000",
  "border":"0px",
  "width": "1px",
  "height": "1px",
  "visiblity":"hidden",
  "font-family": "Lucida Sans Unicode"
 });

 tobj.datepicker({
   showButtonPanel: true,
   dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
   firstDay: 1,
   regional: sprache,
   changeMonth: true,
   showWeek: true, 
   minDate: miniDat,
   maxDate: maxiDat,
   onClose: function () 
        {
         tobj.remove();
        }
  });
 
 tobj.change(function() 
  {
   
   ARCPLAN.arcclient.acSendInputEvent(dateiname, objekt, tobj.val(), 1, 1);
   tobj.remove();
  }
 );
 
 tobj.mouseover(function() 
  {
   $('#dummy_'+objekt+'').focus();
  }
 ); 
 tobj.mouseout(function() 
  {
   $('#dummy_'+objekt+'').focus();
  }
 );
 $('#dummy_'+objekt+'').focus();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```